# An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host - Intermitent

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2014 hosted on Windows server 2012.

I also have many windows services develop in c# that run on Windows Server 2012.

My services have different responsabilities... They then connect on different databases on the server mentionned above.

Sometimes, in a realy intermitent manner, one of the service gets the following SqlException... While they other are still working fine...

```
Message: The client was unable to establish a connection because of an error during connection initialization process before login. Possible causes include the following: the client tried to connect to an unsupported version of SQL Server; the server was too busy to accept new connections; or there was a resource limitation (insufficient memory or maximum allowed connections) on the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)
```

I googled for some troubleshooting info with no luck...

What appears to be strange, it that two service working on the same database on the same server but only one gets the error...

Comment: You might want to tag this with C# as I doubt it's a sql-server issue. Are you using the same connection for both processes?

Comment: No, each process/thread have their own SqlConnection..